# If search matches taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, search

Is it possible to redirect the user to the taxonomy page IF the search input matches the taxonomy name exactly?

For instance i have a taxonomy called "Actors". If someone put into the search field "Tom Hanks" instead of going to the regular search page, it would redirect them to the taxonomy page for Tom hanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Wouldn't this decrease the end user experience?

Comment: @m0r7if3r No totally the opposite. The way my tax page is set up it'll provide a complete overview of the specific taxonomy term on the terms dedicated page. Which is why i'd like to, if possible, redirect the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only wanted to match tags in a single taxonomy, so I was able to simplify the code as follows.  My taxonomy is 'post_tag' -- just swap yours out as needed.

```
$i = 0;
$search_query = get_search_query();

$term = get_term_by( 'name', $search_query, 'post_tag' );
if( $term !== false ) {
    $i++;
    $single_result = $term;
}    

if( $i == 1 && is_object( $single_result ) ) {
    $single_found = true;
} else {
$single_found = false;
unset( $single_result );
}

if( $single_found ) {
    wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/' . $single_result->slug );
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thx

Answer (score 2):

How about something along these lines?

```
$tax_args = array(
    'public' => true
);
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $tax_args, 'names', 'or' );

$i = 0;
foreach( $taxonomies as $tax ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'name', $your_search_term, $taxonomy );
    if( $term !== false ) {
        $i++;
        $single_result = $term;
    }
}

if( $i === 1 && is_object( $single_result ) ) {
    $single_found = true;
} else {
    $single_found = false;
    unset( $single_result );
}

if( $single_found ) {
    wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/' . $single_result->taxonomy . '/' . $single_result->slug );
}
```

Docs: [`get_taxonomies()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies), [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by), [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Comment: hmm no luck on this. Where should i past this code? At the top of my search.php file right? I assume i change $taxonomy with the right taxonomy? Thanks for the effort

Comment: It would likely go there...code's completely untested, you may need to bang on it with a hammer a bit, see where it's failing.